# Error : ErrorDocument to handle the request while submit button clicked to submit message

Tags: javascript, php, html

visit,
[aroma](http://aromapayingguest.com/contact.php)

fill the form and look that its finding some 'please' page.

can anyone help?

```
 function myCustomFunction(){
   if($mail != "" and $comment!= "" and $name!="" and $comment!="")
      {
        $query = "INSERT INTO `vini`.`tab1` (`name`, `email`, `telnumber`,`comment`) VALUES ('$name','$mail','$telnumber','$comment');";
        mysqli_query($conn,$query);

        $recipient = "info@aromapayingguest.com";
        $subject = "Feedback from Aroma Paying Guest Website";
        $message = wordwrap($comment, 70, "\r\n");
        $headers = "From: ". $mail ;
        mail($recipient, $subject, $message, $headers);
        $message = "Thank You, for reaching out to us We will get back to you shortly.\nRegards, Aroma Paying Guest.";
        $headers = "From: noreply@aromapayingguest.com" ;
        mail($mail,$subject,$message,$headers);

    }
    else
        echo "<script>alert('Invalid details');</script>";
}
```

2. `echo "<script>alert('Invalid details');</script>";`

   -- this line is also not working after hosting website

Comment: You mean to say 404 ?

Comment: yes 404 errordocument

Comment: Its related to your apache, do you have .htaccess, make sure rewrite_module is enabled

Comment: no i dont have .htaccess

Comment: ok your action attribute is wrong

Comment: just make `action=""` in your form, I just submitted form also check

Comment: can you ellaborate @AkshayHegde

Comment: how mycustomfunction() will be called then?

Comment: your code is failing on more than one level and you need to use PHP's error reporting and `mysqli_error($conn)` on the query.

Comment: @VinitaWadhwani : added answer

Comment: you should be adding the HTML for this in the question and not have others fetch it from your website, this for a few reasons. You also need to include how you're using that custom method.

Comment: Your code contains too many errors.

Comment: @VinitaWadhwani : at least to make it working you have to set  `action=""` in your form so that it will refer current page for posting data, also take care about sql injection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form action attribute is wrong

What you got is

```
<form id="contact-form" method="post" action= Please enter email address to send mail >
```

What you need is

```
<form id="contact-form" method="post" action="" title="Please enter email address to send mail" >
```

[image]

This is what I got as reply after setting `action=""` in firebug

[image]

Comment: that isn't the only thing wrong

Comment: @Fred-ii- at least if you set `action=""` in firebug form sends mail

Comment: yes but look at their code again and their custom method with the query

Comment: @Fred-ii- true, but  may be that could be model method called inside contact.php index function

Comment: it's a variable scope issue also

Comment: @Fred-ii- we have been guessing, unfortunately OP not giving clear picture of whats there inside :)

Comment: also `$headers = "From: ". $mail ;` is being overwritten by `$headers = "From: noreply@aromapayingguest.com" ;` - their code contains too many errors. They also are not assigning any variables to POST arrays. I feel you may have placed yourself in a rabbit hole here, I'm afraid, but good luck :-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yeah true, actually code which OP shown is not complete, and thats the conclusion, code is not safe too sql injection, and its already hosted, Lord only can save  :) Have a good day, time to leave office

Comment: thanks, have a good day also, *cheers*

Comment: and `echo "<script>alert('Invalid details');</script>";`

-- this line is also not working after hosting website. help ??

Comment: @VinitaWadhwani that script part should render along with other contents of page, thats not happening in your case, if you are on MVC then if validation fails then add script contents to page in your view

Comment: after action="" no entry has been to MySQL

Comment: @VinitaWadhwani: probably you have created `function myCustomFunction()` now am I right ? where `$mail != "" and $comment!= "" and $name!="" and $comment!=""` evaluated to undefined, please revert back your code and just modify action attribute

Comment: yes. thats what my code said in the question

Comment: @VinitaWadhwani will you be able to share contact.php script ? please use this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44779078/revisions) and see your first edit, it worked for me, and got mail too, I don't know what you changed now, if you can share your code I can help you in fixing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147719/discussion-between-vinita-wadhwani-and-akshay-hegde).